# Сравнить в запросе питоновский список и базу ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

Есть список на Питоне, допустим:

```
NAMES = [Alex, Dima, Vika]
```

Как написать такой запрос к базе ClickHouse, который сверяет все значения с этим списком, только с учетом, что имен не 3, а в разы больше, то есть, руками не напишешь.

Например,

```
select
    name
from
    students
where
    name IN |NAMES|
```

Буду признателен за пример для базы ClickHouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увидел удобный ответ в документации, сработал на сравнении таблиц с количеством элементов больше 100к:
https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#external-data-for-query-processing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client

client = Client(host='localhost')

vals_to_check = [2, 4, 8]

rows = client.execute_iter(f'''
    SELECT number
    FROM system.numbers
    WHERE number IN ({','.join(map(str, vals_to_check))})
    LIMIT 10''')

for row in rows:
    print(row[0])

# result:
# 2
# 4
# 8
```

*requirements.txt*

```
clickhouse_driver
```

Comment: спасибо, тестировал этот вариант, он на тестовых данных, где было 5 значений работал, а где было в тысячах выдавал Max query size exceeded.